# Simple way to implement push notifications on Android

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have implemented push notifications on iOS and WP7.

In both cases it wasn't more that 20 lines of code , which was completely self-explainable even to a non-native programmer like i am.

Now i am trying to do the same thing on Android. For the record my application just does 2 things. Opens a webView with a URL inside and registers for push notifications.

What i have found for Android is the sample code within the API and [THIS](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/) tutorial. However is hard to believe that i need 5-6 java classes of 50-80 lines of code each to do such a simple task. I see that the code tries to connect to your server 5 times , waiting every time some period of time before trying again etc etc. I suppose this is only 1 of the many things that are "not-needed" and are just lying around to confuse me more.

Is there a clean and easy way to register for push notifications? I am not interested on registering the token on my server , as i will do that myself. I just need to get the token from the GCM server , nothing more , nothing fancy.

---

For the record i did try to use the sample code , but used to have 2 different kinds of errors:

1) Some times instead of saying i registered in the GCM server , it said that i succesfully unregistered?! I have no idea why this could happen. I just killed the app and start it again and some times i had this message.

2) Some times without any reason when the app is on background i got a message that it crashed and stop working.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what to tell you. Unless you want to write your own push service, Google's GCM is the way to go. Here's the ['Getting Started'](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html) documentation.

Comment: Can you take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15817298/android-sample-code-for-push-notifcations-crashing